# SettingsPropertyNotFoundException - Trying to allow the user to add new keys and values to the config file

Tags: vb.net, winforms, dynamic, app-config, appsettings

I have an application that has configuration for different companies.

Looks like this:

```
<setting name="Instances" serializeAs="String">
    <value>2</value>
</setting>

<setting name="Instance_1_ExportTo" serializeAs="String">
    <value>a/gp_import/</value>
</setting>
<setting name="Instance_1_ImportFrom" serializeAs="String">
    <value>a/gp_export/</value>
</setting>
<setting name="Instance_1_CompanyID" serializeAs="String">
    <value>WCAIR</value>
</setting>
<setting name="Instance_1_Name" serializeAs="String">
    <value>a</value>
</setting>

<setting name="Instance_2_ExportTo" serializeAs="String">
    <value>import/</value>
</setting>
<setting name="Instance_2_ImportFrom" serializeAs="String">
    <value>export/</value>
</setting>
<setting name="Instance_2_CompanyID" serializeAs="String">
    <value>BEAVE</value>
</setting>
<setting name="Instance_2_Name" serializeAs="String">
    <value>b</value>
</setting>
```

Now if i put in all of that, including 1 and 2 into visual studio, compile and run it everything is great.

But if the user changes the "Instances" to 3, and copies and pastes them to make "Instance_3_..." when the application is run, it trys to load Instance_3_Name and gets a property not found exception...? SettingsPropertyNotFoundException

Any help? How can I tell my app that the config file has changed? or does it have to be recompiled?

The property does exist and the config file is loading the "3" from the number of instances, but i guess cause it wasnt there at compile it doesnt exist?

Answer (score 0):

You need to force a re-read of the configuration after it has been modified.

See [programmatically refreshing configuration sections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.refreshsection.aspx).

If you have time to create a custom app.config configuration section then you might find that to be an advantageous pursuit. Also, you will probably need to think about how to trigger the refresh. Will the user need to click a refresh button or do you plan to use a timer? You can also add a file system watcher but this not as straightforward as the other two techniques mentioned above.